# Sum distinct over two one-many relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to sum up the count distinct of one-many relationship inside another one-many relationship. I don't know if that's even possible, but I have to try.

I have three tables as follows:

```
'plan_by_years' 

ID  year    circle_id   ...
1   2018    1   
2   2018    2   
3   2019    1   
4   2020    3
```

and so on, basically one year can have many circles.
Now, each circle can have many members, and operating over the year

```
'members'
ID  member  circle_id
1   A       1
2   B       1
3   C       2
4   C       1
5   D       3
```

I need to get the data into one table so it can be sorted and filtered later. The table has to have the total number of members and total number of circles in a year. Member can only be counted once a year.

The result should look like this:

```
year    number_of_circle    total_member
2018    2                   3
2019    1                   3
2020    1                   1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this result with two separate `COUNT`s, one for circles and one for members. In both cases you need to `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to avoid double counting either circles or members for each year:

```
SELECT p.year,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.circle_id) AS number_of_circle,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.member) AS total_member
FROM plan_by_years p
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.circle_id = p.circle_id
GROUP BY p.year
```

Output:

```
year    number_of_circle    total_member
2018    2                   3
2019    1                   3
2020    1                   1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2P6iVLS44mnRxJgvCUD1Dv/0)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I believe we should expand the relationships before counting.

Comment: @vanq good to hear. I'm not sure what you mean by the rest of your comment?

Comment: It's nothing, before I tried to count members first then sum them when I count the circles but that would be double (or more) counting. It's like a tree diagram where you put data in "compact mode", your answer is like "expand mode" where everything's on parallel lines. I may express it in a confused way, but I hope you get the idea. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @vanq yes, I think I understand what you mean. There are two ways to write this query, one of which uses a derived table which has already counted either the circles or the members. The difficulty with that is dealing with members who belong to more than one circle. That's why I ended up writing the query this way.